2 passports different name one matches green card one needed for entry
I’ve read through threads & haven’t found my exact situation. I’m a green card holder in US. My Ecuadorian passport name matches my green card (First, Father’s Last, Mother’s Last). I’m traveling to the EU & have an Italian passport but the name is First, Fathers Last, Father’s Second Name. So basically my second last name is different. I have to travel on my Ecuadorian passport bc I’m leaving & reentering US & it matches green card. Ecuadorian citizens need a visa where I’m going regardless of green card status. Question is at check in for departure from US when airline asks for proof of eligibility to enter destination country are they going to give me a hard time when I show them the Italian passport with a different second last name?

I have to travel on my Ecuadorian passport bc I’m leaving & reentering US & it matches green card - citation needed. You need to travel on your Ecuadorian passport when you're going back to the US, but you can use your Italian passport on your way to the EU. The question is - does the ticket name match the passport you're traveling on?


I have to travel on my Ecuadorian passport bc I’m leaving & reentering US & it matches green card.

No you don't.  You don't even need a passport to enter the US; your green card is sufficient.
If the name on your ticket matches the Ecuadorian passport:

show both passports when you check in to fly to Europe: the Ecuadorian one to link yourself to the ticket and the Italian one to show that you don't need a visa in the EU.

show the Ecuadorian passport and the green card when you check in to fly to the US.


If the name on your ticket matches the Italian passport:

Show the Italian passport when you check in for the flight to the EU.  In my experience that should be sufficient, but if any question should arise about your immigration status in the US, say "I'm a permanent resident" and, if they want documentary evidence, show your green card.  Only show your Ecuadorian passport if they hesitate because of the difference in the name.

On the way back, show your Italian passport and your green card, and show the Ecuadorian passport only if the name difference comes up.


You can always explain that the names are different because of different naming laws.  The passports tie the different names to you because the image matches you and the details of your birth are the same.  I would be very surprised if it goes as far as your having to explain this.
The above concerns the airlines.  For immigration officers, it's much simpler: always show your Italian passport to officers of EU countries and Schengen member countries; always show your green card to US officers (and, if they ask for it, your passport).

Yes this is my understanding as well. I’m just always afraid of running upon some gatekeeper airline agent who doesn’t understand & somehow refuses boarding. Thanks for the response
